# Detect text content size in TextField

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'd like to reduce the font size in case user types a long text in a [`TextField`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html). Is there a way to know how wide the current text is rendered?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not possible to do directly. You could, however, cheat by using an invisible item that contains the properties you need:

```
Text {
    id: hiddenText
    anchors.fill: tf
    text: tf.text
    font.pixelSize: tf.font.pixelSize
    visible: false
}

TextField {
    id: tf
    width: 100
    height: 60
    font.pixelSize: 25
    onTextChanged: {
        while ((hiddenText.contentWidth > hiddenText.width) || (hiddenText.contentHeight > hiddenText.height)) {
            font.pixelSize -= 1
        }
    }
}
```

You would have to do the same for scaling up the text, in case the user erases some input. The `Text` component does not contain borders, so you have to decrease it's `width` by a few pixels to make it the same size as the `TextField` as well.

Also, check out `TextArea` or `TextInput`. They may fit your need.